# Testing released extension in the Chrome Web Store without review process

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app

I know there are 4 ways to publish extension in Chrome Web Store: Public, Unlisted, Private, Group publishing.
I know as well that publishing goes under a review process that I believe it can take several weeks. So my question is, are all of these 4 ways of publishing under this review process? Because ideally I would like to put a version on chrome store to just 10-20 testers without having to give them the code directly (because I plan to charge it in the future so login/email + install barrier to use the extension is crucial), but at the same time I would like to allow them to test without waiting several weeks for approval.

Thanks!

Read some Chrome Documentation without any direct answer to my specific question.